# Autocomplete on SQL Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, autocomplete, ssms

Does anyone know if there's an add-in that does autocomplete for queries on SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Also found http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/ It does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [Red Gate's SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm).

Answer (score 23):

You can also try Devart's free SQL Complete.

http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/

Comment: They have a paid version and a free version. The free version worked great. I combined it with Red-Gate's free SQL Search and now I can easily find tables and columns in a large database that I only occasionally have to access.

Answer (score 3):

And SQL Server 2008 has autocomplete/IntelliSense built in.

Comment: Works only when connected to 2008 SQL Server. Doesn't work for prior versions.

Comment: [It also doesn't seem to work when you have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482)

Answer (score 2):

[ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx)

have a new version and is a completely free. 
Also if you need add-ins for refactoring your code you have, also free,
[ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx) which will be improved with next release.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Management Studio, but [Toad](http://www.toadworld.com/Products/ToadforSQLServer/tabid/217/Default.aspx) has a freeware version with autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

As previously pointed out, [IntelliSense does not work in SSMS 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2531482) if Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is installed.

I can confirm that upgrading to [SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437) fixed the problem for me. IntelliSense now works in SSMS 2008 R2. *Hooray!*

Comment: Service Pack 2 to the rescue! Thanks, you saved my sanity.

Answer (score 1):

Lately [ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx) has improved a lot - and it is free.

Not everybody likes it, but I am quite a fan.